# В базу данных mysql в неправильной кодировке добавляются записи

Tags: php, mysql

Настройки на поле которое должно выводиться на русском у меня general utf-8
htaccess не использую. Meta charset тоже не использую. 
Но хотелось бы чтобы данные с формы записывались в бд корректно как английский язык, так и русский. Как этого можно достичь?

Comment: @noskovgleb, таких вопросов было много за последний 2-3 недели. Пользуйтесь поиском.

Answer (score 1):

После подключения к БД сделайте пару запросов:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```